# Pointer Problems and Dynamically allocating Memory

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

I'm working on an exercise that will eventually turn into a pthread experiment for educational purposes. Here I'm taking a list (the alphabet) and trying to get five lists of numbers that I can feed to a pthread to analyze something. For example, `numList = 0 5 10 15 20 25` , in the case of the alphabet. Eventually, I'll set it up so pthread will take that list and compare elements at those positions in a list to another thing. I've created a divList function to try and return the above list so I can use it. And though I get the correct results in the function, I'm not returning the list back to main. Is there an obvious error in the way I'm handling the pointer and function?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define num_threads 5

/* Global variable: accessible to all threads */
char *list = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
/* ----------------------------------------- */

int *divList(int MAX, int pos);
void* Hello(void* rank); /* Thread Function */

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, n, thread;
    pthread_t* thread_handles;

    n = strlen(list);
    for (i = 0; i < num_threads; i++){
        if (i <= n % num_threads) // str length / 5 ... remainder 
             //  = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 
            printf("elements: %d\n", divList(n + 1, i));
        else{
            printf("elements: %d\n", divList(n, i));
        }
    }

    thread_handles = malloc (num_threads*sizeof(pthread_t));

    for (thread = 0; thread < num_threads; thread++){
        pthread_create(&thread_handles[thread], NULL, Hello, 
         (void*) thread);
    }

    printf("Hello from the main thread\n");

    for (thread = 0; thread < num_threads; thread++)
        pthread_join(thread_handles[thread], NULL);
    free(thread_handles);
    return 0;   
}   /* MAIN */

int *divList(int MAX, int pos)
{
    int i = 0, j;
    int *numList = malloc(MAX + 1);

    for (j = pos; j < MAX; (j = j + num_threads)){
        numList[i] = j;
        printf("test list: %d\n", numList[i]);
        i++;
    }
    return numList;
}

void* Hello(void* rank) {
    int my_rank = (int) rank; 
    printf("Hello from  thread %d of %d\n", my_rank, num_threads);

    return NULL;
}   /* Hello */
```

Comment: yes, I just fixed that, it was a bad copy and paste

Answer (score 1):

`divList()` returns a pointer to the 1th element of an array of `int` with the number of elements equal to what you passed in to `devList()` as 1st parameter plus 1, which the below code stores in `plist`.

To access the values you could treat the pointer like an array and for example loop to print its values:

```
void printList(int * plist, size_t s)
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < s; ++i)
  {
    printf("element[%zu]: %d\n", i, plist[i];
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i, n, thread;
  int *plist = NULL;
  pthread_t *thread_handles;

  n = strlen(list);
  for (i = 0; i < num_threads; i++)
  {
    if (i <= n % num_threads)  
    {
      plist = divList(n + 1, i);
      printList(plist, n + 1);  /* divList allocates one more then needed 
                                   but never initialises it, so do not print it. */
    }
    else
    {
      ..
```

Comment: This prints out a list in the function right? I'm trying to pass the list back to the main so I can use it when I create the thread.

Comment: Have a look at `plist`.

Comment: I implemented your function in my code and I'm getting something that isn't making a lot of sense. For example: `element[15]: 1852402798`

Comment: `divList()` probably misses to "initialise" all values it allocates? Add some debug calls to `printf()` inside `divList()`s loop to see which elements get assigned which value. Changes this `printf("test list: %d\n", numList[i]);` to become `printf("test list (index=%d): %d\n", i, numList[i]);`

Comment: Also please note that `malloc()` does *not* initialise the memory it allocates. So the content should be considered "garbage".

Comment: Yes, this seems to be working the way I want. test list (index=0): 0
test list (index=1): 5
test list (index=2): 10
test list (index=3): 15
test list (index=4): 20
test list (index=5): 25

Comment: Also this `for (j = pos; j < MAX; (j = j + num_threads)){
        numList[i] = j;` looks fishy. You want to make sure `i` not growing larger then `MAX`.

Comment: I think I will rework this with a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

Your divList function returns an `int *` and you are treating the return value as an `int` (you're printing it with `%d`). You should save the returned value in a variable, because you should free that memory after you use it (every call to divList allocates memory and currently you don't free that).

I'm not sure exactly what you want to do with the array divList gives you, but here is how you can access an element in list:

```
int *arr = divList(n+1, i);
printf("%d\n", arr[5]);
```

Comment: I can free the memory, I had that in there and must've erased it in my crazy troubleshooting. If I return the value in a variable, how do I extract the number list? I wouldn't be using `int *` if I could dynamically allocate the memory with a regular `int`, but, I don't think that possible.

Comment: I added an example to the use of a value in the array. You can modify your question to fix your code, so it will be easier to help that way